# Binding a dropdown with another dropdown in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I am using 2 dropdowns. `ddlCountry` & `ddlState`. My problem is,  when I click on any state in a dropdown the other dropdown should display the Country name. Please help me.

(I am able to do it the other way round. That is, I can display the state names, when i select a country name)

Comment: If you can display the state names when selecting a country, why can't you do the same the way around?
Notice that DropDownList doesn't create postbacks by default when selection changes, so make sure that you set it with AutoPostBack=True (I'm pretty sure that ddlCountry was set like so)

Comment: Thank you for ur reply sir. actually its showing the wrong output. State table consists of only states from India. & in Country table there  are 3 countries. If i select any state from state table, it is showing the country names based on index of country names in country table

Comment: @Abhi You could Set a CountryID as  Foreign key on State Table and fetch the data According to your Selection.

Comment: Thank You sir..I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo code:

```
... id=ddlState autopostback=true onchange=setCountryFromState

setCountryFromState
    get state id
    lookup matching country id from state table
    set ddlCountry value to matching country
```